# Webview android submit form

Tags: javascript, android, forms, webview, submit

I just started using Android Studio (few hours ago).
I created a html form on a web site and i load it via webview.
But the submit button doesn't do anything. Form method is POST.
i tried using javascript function to submit form but it didnt work (it works in browser).

HTML Form:

```
<form name="mt" id="mt" action="http://mywebsite.com/process.php" method="post"> 
<textarea name="tekst"></textarea><br />
<input name="sav" type="radio" value="1" />save
<input name="sav" type="radio" value="2" />preview<br>
 <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a> 
 </form>
```

JS:

```
function submitform()
{
    document.forms["mt"].submit();
}
```

and this is under `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

```
private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
// Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://website.com/form.php");

    }
```

Would be extremely grateful for some insight!

Comment: Which android version are you using? Are you using > 4.0?

Comment: I am using 4.4, should i go lower?

Comment: No in fact I had a similar issue with 2.x. Seems that in your case its not to do with the android version. May be what you can try is replace the href link with a submit button in your html, just to test and see if that works.

Comment: I started with that, but i read somewhere to use javascript for button so i tried that :)

Comment: Try changing <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a> to <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitform()">Submit</a> and check logcat output for possible errors

Comment: Thanks that worked :) 
but now i have a new problem (allow pdf download)